# Copy, paste, sort: Invalid Reference Error

Tags: excel, vba

I can't sort after the third paste.

I want to use `findRange` as the top of the sort range, and use the `destInsertRow` as the bottom of the sorting range. I need that range to resize the selection to include out to column 14, and then sort ascending with `findRange` as the header.

On the second to last line before `Next sourceRowNum`, I get

> invalid reference

```vb
Sub PullTallyNEW()
 ' get source and destination workbook files
    Dim pullFile As String
    MsgBox ("Open Source Tally Workbook.")
    pullFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")  'Copy From'
    Dim putFile As String
    MsgBox ("Open Destination Production List.")
    putFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")   'Insert To'

    'open source workbook
    
    Dim SourceWb As Workbook
    Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=pullFile)
    ' open destination workbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim DestWb As Workbook
    Set DestWb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=putFile)
    Dim destWS As Worksheet: Set destWS = DestWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet: Set sourceWS = SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim sourceRowNum As Long
    For sourceRowNum = 4 To 18 Step 1
        With sourceWS
            Dim findTerm As String
            Select Case True
                Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 4).Value = "(OUTSOURCED)"
                    findTerm = "OUTSOURCED"
                Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 4).Value = "(DESIGN ONLY)"
                    findTerm = "DESIGN; DESIGN ONLY ORDERS"
                Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 5).Value = "No"
                    findTerm = "COMING UP…"
                Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 5).Value = "Yes"
                    findTerm = "DESIGN; PRODUCTION/ACTUAL ORDERS"
                Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 5).Value = "Approved"
                    findTerm = "COMING UP…"
                Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 1).Value = ""
                    findTerm = "ON-HOLD"
                Case Else
            'can add other cases
            End Select
        End With
        With destWS
            Dim findRange As Range
            Set findRange = .Columns(1).Find(findTerm)
            If Not findRange Is Nothing Then
                Dim destInsertRow As Long
                If findRange.Offset(1).Value = "" Then
                    destInsertRow = findRange.Row + 1
                Else
                    destInsertRow = findRange.End(xlDown).Row + 1
                End If
            End If
                destWS.Rows(destInsertRow).Insert xlDown
                
                sourceWS.Cells(sourceRowNum, 11).Resize(1, 3).Copy
                destWS.Cells(destInsertRow, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues), SkipBlanks:=True
                
                sourceWS.Cells(1, 2).Copy
                destWS.Cells(destInsertRow, 5).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
                                
                sourceWS.Cells(sourceRowNum, 6).Copy
                destWS.Cells(destInsertRow, 6).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues), SkipBlanks:=True
                
                destWS.Rows(findRange.Row).Resize(findRange.Row, destInsertRow).Sort key1:=(findRange.Column), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    Next sourceRowNum

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You're using `findRange` outside of the `If Not findRange Is Nothing Then` block...  Seems like that block needs to cover all of the copy/paste code?  Otherwise what happens if no match was made by `Find()` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I have only included headers in the `findRange` that are a part of the sheet template. Thus, all of the terms are findable as constants in 'destWS'. That part of the code works, as expected, but maybe I need the `.sort` function in that  `If Not findRange Is Nothing Then` block?

Comment: If you have a test for `If Not findRange Is Nothing Then` then it should cover all references to `findRange`.   I'm not sure what you're doing here with the resize though `destWS.Rows(findRange.Row).Resize(findRange.Row, destInsertRow)` can you explain what the sort range should be?

Comment: @TimWilliams the sort range should be all rows between `findTerm` and `destInsertRow` with `findTerm` as the header. I was trying to get it to select the `findRange` row (as `findRange` is a range where as `findTerm` is a string) then resize that selection to include every row up to `destInsertRow` and then run `.sort` on that range. (`findRange:destInsertRow`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out - compiled but not tested...

```vb
 Sub PullTallyNEW()
 
    Dim pullFile As String, putFile As String
    Dim SourceWb As Workbook, DestWb As Workbook, destWS As Worksheet, sourceWS As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRowNum As Long, findTerm As String, v1, v4, v5, findRange As Range, destInsertRow As Long
    
    'open source and destination workbook files
    MsgBox ("Open Source Tally Workbook.")
    pullFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")  'Copy From'
    Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=pullFile)
    Set sourceWS = SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    MsgBox ("Open Destination Production List.")
    putFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")   'Insert To'
    Set DestWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=putFile)
    Set destWS = DestWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For sourceRowNum = 4 To 18 Step 1
        With sourceWS
            v1 = .Cells(sourceRowNum, 1).Value
            v4 = .Cells(sourceRowNum, 4).Value
            v5 = .Cells(sourceRowNum, 5).Value
            Select Case True
                Case v4 = "(OUTSOURCED)": findTerm = "OUTSOURCED"
                Case v4 = "(DESIGN ONLY)": findTerm = "DESIGN; DESIGN ONLY ORDERS"
                Case v5 = "No": findTerm = "COMING UP…"
                Case v5 = "Yes": findTerm = "DESIGN; PRODUCTION/ACTUAL ORDERS"
                Case v5 = "Approved": findTerm = "COMING UP…"
                Case Len(v1) = 0: findTerm = "ON-HOLD"
                Case Else: findTerm = ""
            'can add other cases
            End Select
        End With
        
        If Len(findTerm) > 0 Then
            With destWS
                Set findRange = .Columns(1).Find(what:=findTerm) ' good to also specify at least `LookAt`
                If Not findRange Is Nothing Then
                    
                    If findRange.Offset(1).Value = "" Then
                        destInsertRow = findRange.Row + 1
                    Else
                        destInsertRow = findRange.End(xlDown).Row + 1
                    End If
                    
                    destWS.Rows(destInsertRow).Insert xlDown
                    copyValues sourceWS.Cells(sourceRowNum, 11).Resize(1, 3), destWS.Cells(destInsertRow, 1)
                    copyValues sourceWS.Cells(1, 2), destWS.Cells(destInsertRow, 5)
                    copyValues sourceWS.Cells(sourceRowNum, 6), destWS.Cells(destInsertRow, 6)
                    
                    'adjust "X" to cover any/all other columns to be included in the sort...
                    With .Range(findRange, .Cells(destInsertRow, "X"))
                        .Sort key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
                    End With
                End If     'got a match from Find()
            End With
        End If             'have a search term
    Next sourceRowNum

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

'simplify value-only tansfer between ranges
Sub copyValues(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range)
    With rngFrom.Cells(1) 'make sure the destination range size is the same...
        rngTo.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `rngTo.resize` has a typo. Other than that, it works for a single cell transfer. The destination range is repeating the first cell across the row.  However with parts of your answer, I can make the original code work as intended. Thank you!!!